# Measuring vortices in numerical $XY$-like models

Tags: computational-physics, spin-models, vortex

I am simulating an $XY$ model, meaning that I have a $L\times L$ lattice with a unit vector $\vec s_i$ associated with each site. Each $\vec s_i$ is univocally specified by its angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ wrt to a reference direction.

The vorticity $q$ associated to a certain site is defined as
$$
q = \oint \vec{dl} \cdot \nabla \theta = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots
$$
where the contour integral is around a plaquette (i.e., a closed circuit around the reference site). By construction, $q$ can only take integer values.

My question is: how do I get a computer to measure $q$ in correspondence of every site in my discrete lattice, given a certain configuration of all the spins $\vec s_i$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the Computational Science site.

Comment: @Miyase your view of "Physics" looks quite narrow to me, if you vote for excluding computational Physics altogether from its definition. But I'll adapt to the decision of the moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the topological properties of vortices, you only need to consider the phase values at the four points surrounding a square region which may contain a vortex. Let's label the four point $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ in a clockwise direction around the square region. Then you compute the phase differences of consecutive points (e.g. $\phi_b-\phi_a$) and compute their principle values. One way to do this is to multiply/divide the phase factors $\exp(i\phi_b)\exp(i\phi_a)$ and extract the phase from the complex result. Finally you just add these four principle values around the loop. Based on the result, you can set a threshold that will determine whether there is a vortex and what its topological charge is. It is not too difficult to write that all up in a short little program.

Comment: It's a little more subtle than this, since if you do this naïvely you'll always get zero:$$(\phi_b - \phi_a) + (\phi_c - \phi_b) + (\phi_d - \phi_c) + (\phi_a - \phi_d) = 0.$$ You have to be sure to take all of the phase differences mod 2π, so that (for example) the computer knows that the difference between π/8 and 15π/8 should be -π/4 rather than 7π/4.

Comment: That is why you need the principle values as I have explained.

Comment: Ah, I see — I'd never encountered the phrase "principal value" in that context before.

Comment: @flippiefanus but do you agree that, if anything, this recipe is going to yield $q$ in units of $2\pi$, i.e., not an integer by itself?

Comment: @flippiefanus also, if I understand correctly, by "principal value" here you mean measuring angles from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? I tried otherwise and it did not work.

Comment: Yes, if you need integers, you need to divide by $2\pi$. And yes, you need to restrict the phase values to within the range of $-\pi$ to $\pi$.